# What is the difference between printing and exporting a PDF and invoking a graphics device to save a PDF?

Tags: r

I have R 3.5.1 and RStudio 1.1.453 running on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5, platform x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0. I want to understand why I can print and export plots but can't use a graphics device to save the plots.

I can use R's extrafont package to embed the Corbel font into PDF graphs. I can save these graphs by using print() and then exporting via the Plot window. Using this method, the font embeds and displays perfectly.

However, I want R to save several dozen such graphs without having to manually print() and save each one. There are various methods for this.

One is R's [PDF Graphics Device](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html). Unfortunately, this device does not seem to interact nicely with spaces and other characters. Here's the function that produces the ggplot:

```
jobreport_grouped <- function(table, N)
{
  #Group
  table <- table %>%
    group_by(Education, Desired) %>%
    summarize(n())

  #Order
  table <- arrange(table, desc(`n()`))

  #Response label
  response_count <- sum(table$`n()`)

  #Sample size label
  samplesize <- paste("(N = ", sum(table$`n()`), ")", sep="")

  #Grouped barplot
  ggplot(table[which(table$`n()`>N),],
         aes(fill=Education, 
             x=reorder(Desired,-`n()`), 
             y=`n()`)
         ) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = paletteIDCN) +
    IDCNtheme_grouped_dense +
    xlab(paste("Number of Active Members: ", 
               member_count, 
               "\n", 
               "Number of Responses: ", 
               response_count, 
               sep="")
         ) +
    ylab("Number of IDCN Members") +
    ggtitle(paste(desired_title("Professional Areas"), 
                  "\n",
                  today, 
                  sep = ""
                  )
            )+
    geom_col(position="dodge")  
}
```

And then a call of this function along with an attempt to write the plot

```
> getGroupedJobReport <- function(A,n){
    +   p <- jobreport_grouped(A,n)
    +   ggsave(p, filename = "~/TMP-R/TDP/plots/Desired_GROUPED.pdf", device = pdf,
    +          width = 12, height = 7, units = "in")
    + }
    > getGroupedJobReport(A1,2)
    There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
    > warnings()
    Warning messages:
    1: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
      font width unknown for character 0x20
    2: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
      font width unknown for character 0x27
    3: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
      font width unknown for character 0x20
```

After this, I tried a MacPorts installation of [Cairo](https://cairographics.org/) together with [CRAN's Cairo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cairo/index.html) package and got a different error:

```
> getGroupedJobReport <- function(A,n){
+   p <- jobreport_grouped(A,n)
+   ggsave(p, filename = "~/TMP-R/TDP/plots/Desired_GROUPED.pdf", device = cairo_pdf,
+          width = 12, height = 7, units = "in")
+ }
> getGroupedJobReport(A1,2)
Warning message:
In dev(file = filename, width = dim[1], height = dim[2], ...) :
  failed to load cairo DLL
```

What alternatives to R's native PDF Graphics Device and Cairo are there? If any, which ones should I think of using?

Comment: Have you tried `pdf(...); your_plot; dev.off()`?

Comment: I've tried that, which is a standard invocation of the graphics device. R throws the same font width error.